# Sequelize JS - Choose On clause in join

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i want to know how i can choose the `ON` clause in a join. I have two tables, `packages` and `users`. The `package` table has two fields/columns (owner_id, helper_id) that are foreign keys to the same table `users`. I want to have one for joining where `packages.owner_id = users.id` and `packages.helper_id = users.id`. here is what i have:

```
models.Packages.findAll({
    where: (!package_id ? { owner_id } : { owner_id, id: { [Op.lt]: package_id } }),
    include: [{
      model: models.Users,
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
      where: ['helper_id = id']
    }],
    limit: 5,
    order: [["id","DESC"]]
  })
```

and the other

```
models.Packages.findAll({
    where: (!package_id ? { owner_id } : { owner_id, id: { [Op.lt]: package_id } }),
    include: [{
      model: models.Users,
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
      where: ['owner_id = id']
    }],
    limit: 5,
    order: [["id","DESC"]]
  })
```

but i get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed
```

help please?

Comment: I don't believe the `where` parameter takes an array of strings as you have defined. Try passing an object: `where: { helper_id: id }`

Comment: @mcranston18 but those variables don't exist in the scope, there isn't an actual value. i want to define the ON clause in the JOIN statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `Shahar Hadas`'s answer, but i did find how to solve what i am looking to do.

Basically, i had to define a relationship/association with specific aliases (notice the `as` property):

```
models.Users.hasMany(models.Packages, { foreignKey: 'owner_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
models.Users.hasMany(models.Packages, { foreignKey: 'helper_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
models.Packages.belongsTo(models.Users, { as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'owner_id', targetKey: 'id' });
models.Packages.belongsTo(models.Users, { as: 'helper', foreignKey: 'helper_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

then when i query, i can choose the alias i want:

```
models.Packages.findAll({
    where: (!package_id ? { owner_id } : { owner_id, id: { [Op.lt]: package_id } }),
    include: [{
      model: models.Users,
      as: 'owner',
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
    }],
    limit: 5,
    order: [["id","DESC"]]
  })
```

or

```
models.Packages.findAll({
    where: (!package_id ? { owner_id } : { owner_id, id: { [Op.lt]: package_id } }),
    include: [{
      model: models.Users,
      as: 'helper',
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
    }],
    limit: 5,
    order: [["id","DESC"]]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should like:

```
models.Packages.findAll({
    where: (!package_id ? { owner_id } : { owner_id, id: { [Op.lt]: package_id } }),
    include: [{
      model: models.Users,
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
      where: { 'helper_id': Sequelize.col('Users.id') },
    limit: 5,
    order: [["id","DESC"]]
  })
```

For further information, look at Sequelize docs at:
[sequelizejs Relations / Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#relations---associations)

Comment: i think you meant `Sequelize.col('Users.id')`? thanks for sharing.

Comment: yep my bad, I'll delete the 2nd example ... it was cut & paste. the 1st one should be the right one

Comment: if you still need help with the 2nd example on your question - let me know

Comment: it still says `Sequelize.col('Packages.id')`. i want to include the Users model so shouldn't it be `Sequelize.col('Users.id')`?

Comment: you are correct,
One additional comment, it might be better on the SQL to rewrite the 1st `where` with Seuqelize operators (and let the SQL engine do the work for you) - this way the SQL generation will be more consistent for the database engine (hence will might be optimized better)

Comment: Thanks, this helps!